# Join two tables data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below code is showing parametersname from DataModel table(data base).I have one more table  DataModelDevices which has parameter_name column.I want to show parameter_name as well in same row in UI. How to join one more table in rails?
I have tried below code but not working.

```
 <% DataModel.preload(:devices,:revision).where(device: true).where("parametersname NOT LIKE '%.'").where("parametersname LIKE '%{i}%'").order(:id).each do |parameter| %>
            <tr onclick="javascript:showRowDeviceTest(this);">

           <% DataModelDevices.all.each do |parameterhard| %>
                  <td style="word-break:break-all;">
                <%= parameter.parametersname%>

                    <%= parameterhard.parameter_name%>
                  </td>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
```

Actual Working Code

```
            <% DataModel.preload(:devices,:revision).where(device: true).where("parametersname NOT LIKE '%.'").where("parametersname LIKE '%{i}%'").order(:id).each do |parameter| %>
                <tr onclick="javascript:showRowDeviceTest(this);">

                  <td style="word-break:break-all;">
                    <%= parameter.parametersname%>
                  </td>

                  </tr>
                <% end %>
```

Comment: Start by cleaning up your code. Avoid creating long or complex queries in the view (move it to the controller) - the view should pretty much just take data and render it in the simplest way possible. Also you should make the naming consistent - use snake_case. Using both `parametersname` and `parameter_name` is a distaster waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

you should add association in the models In DataModel:

`has_many :data_model_devices`

In DataModelDevice: 
`belongs_to :data_model`

You can join with the following code whatever you want:

```
DataModel.joins(:data_model_devices).
select('data_model_devices.parameter_name, data_models.*').load
```

Comment: Thanks.I am getting undefined local variable or method `data_model_devices' for #<#<Class:0x00007f9d8a5ee6b8>:0x00007f9d8e571588>

Comment: If you have a model with name `DataModelDevice` and add related association in both model, that code should run without error.

Comment: yes.I have model data_model_devices.rb and name DataModelDevices.I have added related association as well.

Comment: your model name should be `DataModelDevice` not 'DataModelDevices'

Comment: This is the latest code i am working in.<% DataModel.joins(:hard_data_model).select(hard_data_model.parameter_name,data_model.*).preload(:devices,:revision,:hard_data_model).where(device: true).where("parametersname NOT LIKE '%.'").where("parametersname LIKE '%{i}%'").order(:id).each do |parameter| %>

Comment: Not DataModelDevice.Changed to HardDataModel

Comment: But still getting same error hard_data_model is undefined

Comment: your select content should be inside ''
`select('hard_data_model.parameter_name,data_model.*')`

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: data_model: SELECT hard_data_model.parameter_name,data_model.* FROM "data_models" INNER JOIN "hard_data_models" ON "hard_data_models"."data_model_id" = "data_models"."id" WHERE "data_models"."device" = ? AND (parametersname NOT LIKE '%.') AND (parametersname LIKE '%{i}%')  ORDER BY "data_models"."id" ASC

Comment: your tables has `s` in the end of names
`select('hard_data_models.parameter_name,data_models.*')`

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: hard_data_models.data_model_id: SELECT hard_data_models.parameter_name,data_models.* FROM "data_models" INNER JOIN "hard_data_models" ON "hard_data_models"."data_model_id" = "data_models"."id" WHERE "data_models"."device" = ? AND (parametersname NOT LIKE '%.') AND (parametersname LIKE '%{i}%')  ORDER BY "data_models"."id" ASC

Comment: I am using this now

Comment: <% DataModel.joins(:hard_data_model).select('hard_data_models.parameter_name,data_models.*').preload(:devices,:revision).where(device: true).where("parametersname NOT LIKE '%.'").where("parametersname LIKE '%{i}%'").order(:id).each do |parameter| %>